# haartrainingユーティリティがエラーで落ちる

Tags: opencv

OpenCVで機械学習用のXMLを作っています。以下のサイトを参考にしました。
[Haar状特徴に基づくブースト分類器のカスケードを利用する高速物体検知](http://www.wikihouse.com/penny/index.php?Haar%BE%F5%C6%C3%C4%A7%A4%CB%B4%F0%A4%C5%A4%AF%A5%D6%A1%BC%A5%B9%A5%C8%CA%AC%CE%E0%B4%EF%A4%CE%A5%AB%A5%B9%A5%B1%A1%BC%A5%C9%A4%F2%CD%F8%CD%D1%A4%B9%A4%EB%B9%E2%C2%AE%CA%AA%C2%CE%B8%A1%C3%CE#step3)

createsamples ユーティリティを使用して一枚のポジティブイメージから1000のポジティブイメージを構築しました。以下のコマンドにな入ります。

```
>createsamples.exe -img data.bmp -vec positive.vec -num 1000
```

次に、haartrainingユーティリティに先ほど作った`positive.vec`と`bg.txt`を与え実行しました

```
>haartraining.exe -data data.xml -vec positive.vec -bg bg.txt -npos 1000 -nneg 359
```

初回`bg.txt`の内容は`~.jpg`と`~.bmp`と`~.gif`と`~.png`がリストになったもので実行しましたが

```
*** 1 cluster ***
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (elements_read == 1) in icvGetHaarTraininDataFrom
VecCallback, file ..\..\..\..\..\..\xx\documents\visual studio 2010\Proj
ects\OpenCV\haartraining\cvhaartraining.cpp, line 1861
```

とエラーが出たため内容を`~.jpg`と`~.bmp`にしましたが
またエラーが出たため`~.jpg`のみにしましたがまだエラーが出ています

私の予想では画像のピクセル数や容量によるエラーかと思われます

OpenCVでエラーが出ないピクセル数やファイル容量を教えて下さい

OpenCV v2.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 *** 1 cluster *** OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (elements_read == 1) in icvGetHaarTraininDataFrom VecCallback, file OpenCV\haartraining\cvhaartraining.cpp, line 1861
```

`line 1861`はフォルダが残っていると出るエラーです。
対象内に出来たファイルとフォルダーを削除してください。

Answer (score 1):

落ちる現象ですが、

```
\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin\opencv_haartraining.exe
```

の方を実行するようにした結果治りました。
同一フォルダ内にDLLファイルが存在しないために起きていたようです。

また別のエラー(`line 2xxx`か`line 5xxx`だったかと)ですが`bg.txt`内のファイル数より少ない数値を`-nneg`や`-npos`に与えることで解消出来ました。