# OpenCV 画像検出の分類器作成で、createsamples/traincascade/haartaraining が止まる

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

OpenCV 2.4.10 使用でコマンドプロンプトでポジティブサンプルとネガティブサンプルを作成して学習させて XML ファイルを作成したいのですが、ポジティブサンプルを作る際にも vec ファイルは作成されているのですが容量は 0 なんですけど正常に作成されていますか？

ポジティブサンプルは 1 枚からサンプルを 7000 枚作成しようと考えています。ネガティブサンプルは 300 枚用意しました。

ポジティブサンプルを作る際に `createsamples` で実行したところ動作を停止しましたと出るのですがどうしたら良いですか？一応 vec ファイルは出来ています。

学習する時の `traincascade` と `haartaraining` も動作を停止しましたと出てしまいます。

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Unable to read negative images) in cvCreateTree
CascadeClassifier, file ........\opencv\apps\haartraining\cvhaartraining.cpp,
line 2434
```

これが出てきますがどういう意味なんですか？

Answer (score 1):

一通りはこちらに書いたのですが重複の質問ではないと判断されたので回答しますね。

> [haartrainingユーティリティがエラーで落ちる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5364/haartraining%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%81%8C%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A7%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8B)

動作を停止してしまうということは、正常ではなさそうですね。

```
\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin\
```

フォルダ内にある

```
opencv_createsamples.exe
opencv_traincascade.exe
opencv_haartraining.exe
```

の方を実行していますか。
同一フォルダ内にDLLファイルが存在しない可能性はありませんか？